# How to best serve larger files in cloud cdn?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cdn

I have a cloud cdn which primarily has been serving high res images for our visualization platform.

but lately we have started to get more into 3d content.

this content is served as .glb files (binary gltf).
and are often in the range 8-40mb

in the documentation for cloud cdn it mentions that the cdn will not cache files larger than 10mb.

https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#maximum-size

Since we are going to serve more and more large 3d files, and it does not feel good relying on only the underlying cloud storage bucket.
Our bucket is placed in europe

What are my options?

Comment: 1/2) The primary goal of a CDN is to deliver frequent content faster to end-users. This typically means the CSS, JS, and images on web pages. Cloud Storage buckets are very reliable, so I do not understand that concern. The Internet is not reliable, but the user is still using the Internet to access your data (CDN or Bucket).

Comment: 2/2) The difference will be that the CDN POP is usually closer to the user minimizing the distance that data travels over the public Internet. Most problems are the "last mile" so if reliability is the concern, a CDN will not solve that type of issue. If you must use a caching CDN then select another CDN that caches larger content. You can deploy more than one CDN.

Comment: If my bucket is placed in europe, but the cloud cdn allows me to cache files around the world in its edge caches. I now have users that are going to try to access our 3d scenes across the globe, and I now want them to download the the 3d assets from the closest cache also.

Comment: Then you will need to deploy a different CDN that meets your goal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cloud CDN to provide files up to 5 TiB if the origin server supports byte range requests, and Cloud Storage supports it (if the content-encoding is not gzip).

https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#byte-range-requests